# Reverse a JS, If Then Code to Negative

Tags: javascript, reverse

I have a code that currently tells a site to **only** load something if it finds certain text in the class #nav.

I would like to reverse the code so it loads the code **unless** it finds certain text in the #nav.  Help?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if ($('#nav:contains(Scary Text)').length) {
    var t_award = {
        name: "Hello",
        thumbnail: [20, 20],
        closeFunction: "fade",
        users: [
            [user ID, "award name", "image", "award description", "award date"]
        ]
    }
    $.getScript('http://z3.ifrm.com/142/141/0/p239659/tooltipawards.js');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I imagine it'll be hard to test this code unless you have a zetaboards forum, but I'm pretty sure some one who knows JS can help :)

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Use an exclamation point to make the condition inversed: `if (!$('#nav:contains(Scary Text)').length) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use the :not selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

`if ($('#nav:not(:contains(Scary Text))').length) {`